Cannot connect to git (Gitea) server. Permission denied
Recently I selfhosted Gitea server via docker container.
Also I have nginx reverse proxy on host machine (with certbot SSL).
I generated added ssh keys via tutorial provided by gitea and gh, but getting the following error while testing connection to gitea server
Log file of ssh -vvv (stackoverflow thinks that is spam)
https://pastebin.com/31haL5bV

$ ssh-add -l -E sha256

Shows the same i have configured in gitea server.
Tried different options to fix it but no result. Also could not understand where is the problem exactly.
I expect to connect to my git server and perform create on push operation (at least).
